# Away3d materials

Tags: flash, away3d

how i can delete this wire lines that devide my prism on triangles? http://img217.imageshack.us/img217/1535/31477485.jpg

Comment: and i want http://img203.imageshack.us/img203/480/46640164.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create colormaterial and set this
exp:

```
 mycube.material = new ColorMaterial();
```